# Cannot find module 'Moment' at npm build

Tags: angular, github-actions, npm-build

I am getting error Cannot find module 'Moment' at npm build step in GitHub Action.

Not sure if it is installing 'Moment' module or not.

The build is working fine on local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to host runner Linux, capitalisation fix were done to fix the above issue.